# Hyper-V Missing Virtual Server From Hyper-V Manager List

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, backup-restoration, snapshot

We are running Hyper-V on a Window 2008 server that doesn't have a desktop (only console login is provided).

We access Hyper-V using Hyper-V Manager which connects to this host-server and it provides a GUI for managing our virtual machines.

Today, after receiving notification of numerous problems occurring on the network, I launched Hyper-V manager to discover that the company's primary active directory server was missing from the list of virtual machines!

I logged into the host's console and found the folder where the virtual disk drive were located. Since the virtual machine was no longer listed in Hyper-V Manager, the only thing I knew to do was create a new virtual machine, and mount the same virtual drives c and d to this new virtual server instance.

After doing this, the server booted up, but all the files on the file system were from October of 2012.

There are current snapshots (avhd files) of the server, but since I booted the server from the vhd file first, I understand that I've corrupted the ability to merge to the snap shot. If there's a way around this please tell me.

Also, now that the server is running, Active Directory isn't working properly. Many mapped network drives are giving users access denied errors. I've removed sharing from each of these folders and have added sharing back, but I continue to struggle. Share printers aren't being shared anymore. Too many issues to mention!

There is a secondary domain controller (on a physical machine), but now that this primary server is running (like its October 2012) I assume it is replicating over the 2nd domain control server that never went down.

What's the best thing for me to do. Am I going to have just rebuild the whole network from scratch to get all these issues resolved? Or is there a way that I can get the other machines on this network to forgive this outdated Active Directory server?

I have backups of all the important files that are missing, but I'm not sure how to get this Active Directory server forgiven for jumping back in time so many months.

Please advise, I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: 1. Stop flailing around. The way to fix something is not to break everything else in the process. Focus on the core problem, which is figuring out why the DC isn't listed in Hyper-V Manager. 2. After the initial reboot was the DC VM still missing? Is the Hyper-V host a Failover Cluster member?

Comment: Which domain controller holds your FSMO roles?

Comment: The DC is up an running now, but it is as though I turned it off in October of 2012 and then turned it on today. I'm not sure about FSMO roles I've never heard of them and am looking that up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can likely merge the AVHDs back into the VHD but you will need the original VHD file.  (You had shadow copies turned on, right??? RIGHT?!!)  There is a walkthrough here:  http://itproctology.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-manually-merge-hyper-v-snapshots.html#!/2008/06/how-to-manually-merge-hyper-v-snapshots.html

You can attempt an import as well, but if I recall (and I might be mistaken) an import on 2008 will only work if the VM has been exported.  So you might be out of luck there..